# Docker - Was trying to move Docker off my C: drive, messed something up now I can't reinstall it (Windows 10)

Tags: docker, windows-10

I was trying to move Docker off my C: drive using the guidance below:

https://forums.docker.com/t/how-could-i-install-docker-for-windows-on-drive-e-my-ssd-c-is-full/52347/12

I completed the final step: **sc.exe config com.docker.service binPath=“D:\Program Files\Docker\com.docker.service”** and it seemed to work. But when I went to run Docker, it wouldn't run, so I deleted it off my E: drive.

But now, when I try to reinstall it, it says Docker is already installed. I go to Apps & Features to uninstall it, but it gives me:

**Windows cannot find 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker Desktop Installer.exe'. Make sure you typed the name correctly,  and then try again.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having had Docker removed from my PC and running into the same issue while reinstalling, the only way that worked for me was looking up the Docker application within the Windows Registry Editor and deleting it from there.

You would need to open up Registry Editor or use Run and type in regedit, and within this path look for anything mentioning "Docker", "Docker Desktop" or the path that windows "cannot find":

**Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall**

source from when I had issues: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1371#issuecomment-347926743